# Is there any terminology to call a non-stop, while true programme?

Tags: terminology

For example, I have a programme, which is keep scanning the internet website, which won't stop, and keep working, when it start to work.... Is there any special name/terminology calling this kind of programme? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> One possibility is *daemon* - [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29)
>
> – Paul R Dec 30 '11 at 17:04